# Proof that matrices of the form $e^X$ are a group under matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, group-theory, matrix-exponential

I have searched but could not find the information.

It is well known that

$$
\exp \mathfrak{gl} \to GL^+
$$

is only surjective if $\mathfrak{gl}$ are the complex-valued matrices. If they are real valued, the map is not surjective.

But then from the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), we know that there exists many matrices such that $e^Xe^Y=e^Z$.

Can we say that exponentials of matrices are a group under multiplication? Because $\forall X \forall Y: e^Xe^Y=e^Z$, as per the formula above?

Comment: Even if we ignore the "sufficiently small" hypothesis, that equation only says that exponentials of matrices are closed under multiplication—a group has other hypotheses that must be checked.

Comment: @GregMartin The inverse of $e^X$ is $e^{-X}$. The identity is $e^0=1$. And it is associative $(e^Xe^Y)e^A=e^X(e^Ye^A)$.

Comment: @GregMartin The question remaining is "does the multiplication of two sufficiently small matrices always produce a sufficiently small matrice".

Comment: As a side note, why in the world would you include a *screenshot of Wikipedia* in your question? It's Wikipedia! You can link to it! You can copy and paste! Either one of those would have been more useful.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that "sufficiently small" is closed under multiplication. If $X$ is sufficiently small, is $nX$ sufficiently small for all positive integers $n$? (since $(e^X)^n = e^{nX}$)

Comment: @GregMartin Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula in the section "Existence results", it seems to suggest that the exponentials of matrices form a grouplike if they are sufficiently small, and elements of a grouplike are closed under multiplication. But I cannot parse the text with certainty, because there are too many unfamiliar concepts to me. Can you kindly check and share your opinion?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Quite interesting. I guess I have my work cut out. Any thing else you want to chip in would be appreciated.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I don't suppose I could beg you for a fetched out proof? Please.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I added a bounty, if you would like to have a go.

Comment: The statement you are after is simply false. My suggestion is to examine the image of the space of real 2x2 matrices under $\exp$ and check that it is not a group.

Comment: Apparently, a (real) matrix has a logarithm if and only if it has an inverse and a square root. See [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145430/if-a-is-a-real-non-singular-square-matrix-then-there-exists-a-real-matrix-b-s), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977963/the-measure-of-the-image-of-the-exponential-of-real-matrices), [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522359/writing-real-invertible-matrices-as-exponential-of-real-matrices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment of @Moishe Kohan:

Given a $2\times2$ matrix $M$, let $t=\text{tr}(M)$ be the trace of $M$, let $F=\text{tf}(M)$ be the trace-free part of $M$, so $M=\tfrac t2I+F$, and let $d=\det(F)$ be the determinant of $F$. A straightforward calculation (or Cayley-Hamilton) gives $F^2=-d\,I$, so the exponential is

$$\exp(M)=\exp(\tfrac t2)\exp(F)=\exp(\tfrac t2)\cdot\begin{cases}\cos(\sqrt d)\,I+\frac{1}{\sqrt d}\sin(\sqrt d)\,F,\quad d>0\\I+F,\quad d=0\\\cosh(\sqrt{-d})\,I+\frac{1}{\sqrt{-d}}\sinh(\sqrt{-d})\,F,\quad d<0\end{cases}$$

$$=M'=\tfrac{t'}2I+F'$$

The trace of this is

$$t'=\text{tr}(\exp(M))=\exp(\tfrac t2)\cdot\begin{cases}2\cos(\sqrt d),\quad d>0\\2,\quad d=0\\2\cosh(\sqrt{-d}),\quad d<0\end{cases}$$

and the trace-free part is

$$F'=\text{tf}(\exp(M))=\exp(\tfrac t2)\cdot\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt d}\sin(\sqrt d)\,F,\quad d>0\\F,\quad d=0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{-d}}\sinh(\sqrt{-d})\,F,\quad d<0\end{cases}$$

which has determinant

$$d'=\det(F')=\exp(t)\cdot\begin{cases}\sin^2(\sqrt d),\quad d>0\\0,\quad d=0\\-\sinh^2(\sqrt{-d}),\quad d<0\end{cases}$$

The important part is that if $d'<0$ (or $d'=0$ and $F'\neq0$) then $t'>0$.

We can take any matrix $M$ with $d\leq0$, and multiply the two exponentials $\exp(M)=M'$ and $\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&-\pi\\\pi&0\end{bmatrix}\right)=-I$, to get another matrix $M''=-M'$. This has $d''=d'\leq0$ and $F''=-F'$ but $t''=-t'<0$, so $M''$ cannot be a single exponential.

For example:

$$M''=\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&-\pi\\\pi&0\end{bmatrix}\right)\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}-e&0\\0&-1/e\end{bmatrix}$$

$$t''=\text{tr}(M'')=-e-1/e<0$$

$$F''=\text{tf}(M'')=\frac{-e+1/e}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$d''=\det(F'')=-\left(\frac{-e+1/e}{2}\right)^2<0$$

Thus, the image of $\exp$ is not a group.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. For example,
$$\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix} \ \text{and}\ \exp \begin{bmatrix} 0&\pi \\ -\pi&0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} -1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
However,
$$\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0&\pi \\ -\pi&0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1&-1 \\ 0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is not the exponential of any real matrix.

The point is that the BCH formula gives a formula for $\exp(X) \exp(Y)$ as the exponential of a formal sum, but that sum may or may not be convergent, and the particular matrices in my example are outside the radius of convergence.

See the [Wikipedia article on the BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence).

Comment: "... is not the exponential of any real matrix." - Why?

Comment: In the context of my answer, the reason would be that it has negative trace ($t'<0$, hence $d>0$), and its trace-free part is non-zero but has zero determinant ($d'=0$, hence $\sin^2(\sqrt d)=0$), which is impossible for an exponential (as $\sin(\sqrt d)=0$ implies $F'=0$, a contradiction).

Comment: The usual way I see this verified is: If $e^X$ were this matrix, then the generalized eigenvalues of $X$ would have to in $(\pi i) + (2 \pi i) \mathbb{Z}$. Since $X$ is real, the set of its generalized eigenvalues would be closed under complex conjugation, so they must be $\pm (2 k+i) (\pi i)$ for some $k$. But then $X$ would have  distinct complex eigenvalues, so it would be complex diagonalizable, so $e^X$ would be complex diagonalizable, contradiction.

Comment: I'm sure there are many other ways to do this.